# Finding number of Iterations

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to find the number of iterations an algorithm does when sorting.

How we find the number of iterations built in `sort:Collections.sort` does when sorting?

Comment: Any reason? Time? Recursion? Curiosity?

Comment: Sorry, this is too broad and unclear to be answered.  What do you mean by "iteration"?  In a purely recursive sort the answer is "zero", so I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: The default sorting algorithm in Java is Tim sort, which is a modified merge sort. Looking that up will probably be a lot more meaningful. If you don’t know where to look, check the Java source code, it has great documentation on the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can count the number of iterations at run time. (You could count them using a debugger, but I don't think that's what you mean.)

You *can* count the number of comparisons done by `Collections.sort()` by using the two-argument version of the method and passing your own comparator that counts how many times it is called. That's probably a more meaningful measure of sorting work than counting iterations.